# DataGridView doesn't apply changes

Tags: c#

i'm attaching the code.
i'm trying to delete a raw and append it to the original database with datagridview.
i successively get the datagridview, but the modifications are not saved.

i cannot hav the datagridview save anything, it just pops right back up on next launch.
thank you so much in advance.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServerName\\InstanceName;Initial Catalog="+ comboBox1.Text + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                string sqlQuery = @"SELECT * from " + comboBox2.Text;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(table);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
                myConnection.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                DialogResult question = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if ( question == DialogResult.Yes)

                {

                   dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
                   dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                   myConnection.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code which deletes the row in the database, what you show is how you are removing them from the `datagridview`

Comment: can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `dataGridView1.Bind();`

Code Should be:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MyServerName\\InstanceName;Initial Catalog="+ comboBox1.Text + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;");
                string sqlQuery = @"SELECT * from " + comboBox2.Text;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(table);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
                dataGridView1.DataBind();
                myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: It seems that his code is `winforms` there is no `DataBind` method for `DataGridView`

Answer (score 0):

Get the primary key of the table from the SelectedRow of the Grid and perform delete operation in DB table separately.

Try this out.

DB script, Before running this create a DB called **"TestDB"**

```
   USE [TestDB]
      GO

      /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Student]    Script Date: 05/24/2013 14:54:09 ******/
     SET ANSI_NULLS ON
     GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
     GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
         [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
         [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
         [Age] [int] NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
           [ID] ASC
             )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =                   OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
   ) ON [PRIMARY]

   GO
```

C# code

For Grid binding

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT * from Student" ;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
        myConnection.Close();

    }
```

For Deleting the row

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            DialogResult question = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure?", "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if ( question == DialogResult.Yes)

            {
                MessageBox.Show(item.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString());
                DeleteFromTable(Convert .ToInt32  (item.Cells["ID"].Value));

               //dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
               //dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);




            }
            else
            {

                break;
            }
        }


    }


    public void DeleteFromTable(int primaryKey)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
        string sqlQuery = @"DELETE FROM Student WHERE ID = " + primaryKey + "(SELECT * from Student)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, myConnection);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(table);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource(table, null);
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

I hope this solves your purpose.

Comment: can you please elaborate? maybe give an example?